# ffmpeg concat videos with own audio and add a soundtrack 50% volume

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a list of file in a txt, I need to concat (files are same codec and size and have sound), than i need to add a soundtrack with 50% volume. Thanks

This is the command I use to concat but this substitute the audio with the new soundtrack, instead I need to mix with the original sound in the file, and I need to control the volume of the soundtrack.
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "concat:file.txt" -i "soundtrack.mp3" -c copy "output.mp4"

Comment: how to use map? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

volume 0.5, mix audio, copy video:

> ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i file.txt -i soundtrack.mp3 -filter_complex "
> [1]volume=0.5[1a];[0:a][1a]amix" -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac -q:a 4
> output.mp4